# how b3dm and pnts files are generated

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am checking [3d tiles](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/tree/3d-tiles) branch. I could successfully build this branch on my local environment and now I am trying to analyze how custom tiles can be written. 
I tried viewing `b3dm` and `pnts` files but my editor shows junk characters in this file.

How can these files be written for my requirement? Or what is the way these files can be generated? Can I write a program to generate this kind of file?

Answer (score 1):

To create b3dm, you can use the software in the "tools" directory of the [3d-tiles-tools](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/3d-tiles-tools/) repository, which contains a converter to go from glb to b3dm and also i3dm.

You see "junk characters" in your text editor because this is a packed binary file format; your data is not stored in characters. b3dm is glTF with a header added, but glTF comes in two versions -- a binary and a text version and b3dm uses the binary version. The exact description of the 3d Tiles formats are given at https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/3d-tiles -- click the links under "spec status." If you want to see the actual coordinate numbers in those files you can do it with a hex editor.